# headheight and footheight bzw footskip

Tags: header-footer

I’ve been using Latex for half a year now, have already made a presentation, consulted the KOMA-Script very often and unfortunately still don’t understand how the header height works in detail and as intended in KOMA-Script. I’m sure I’m overlooking something very simple. Why doesn’t Latex respond to the header height setting? And I can’t tell you how I changed the footer height either. I’ve left some of my attempts in the code, but commented out. I’m open to constructive criticism, but I HAVE already searched for a long time and can’t find a suitable answer for me. Thank you very much for your help, but I don’t know if I’ll look at it again today.
I deleated the commands defined by me. Sure i had to deleate inputenc[T1], usualy i comment this out.
The large issue is no big thing, i changed but unfortunaley not in this code.
The question is the headheigth.
Thaks again
Patrick

```
   \documentclass[BCOR=2.25mm, 
footheight=1cm,
titlepage=false,
%table,
%textwidth=10cm, 
parskip=half+, fontsize=12pt,
%headsepline,%fügt eine Linie in den Kopf ein
%headlines=2,
headheight=60pt,
%headskip=10pt,
%foodskip=100pt,
DIV=16,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\usepackage[%headheight=100pt,footskip=100pt]{geometry}

%\KOMAoptions{headheight=100pt}
%\KOMAoptions{footheight=100pt}

%\pagestyle{scrheadings}

%\areaset{16cm}{21cm}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{comment}
%\setmainfont{Futura Book BT}[ItalicFont = Futura Book Italic %BT,BoldFont = Futura Heavy BT,BoldItalicFont = Futura Heavy Italic %BT ]

\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable, tabularx, tabulary, tabu}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{stackengine} %für extrarow?
\usepackage{wasysym}%Für Haken und Kästchen
\newcommand{\myjobname}{}
\StrGobbleRight{\jobname}{1}[\myjobname] %jobname wird in myjobname gespeichert und das erste Zeichen (Anfürhugnszeichen) entfernt.
\StrGobbleLeft{\myjobname}{1}[\myjobname]%jobname wird in myjobname gespeichert und das letzte Zeichen (Anfürhugnszeichen) entfernt.
\newcommand{\mytitle}{\myjobname}

%\clearpairofpagestyles % Clear headers and footers

\rohead{\includegraphics[height=50pt]{c:/Schule/logo_rot_3.jpg}}

\lofoot{\jobname}
\cfoot[\pagemark\ von \pageref{LastPage}]{\pagemark\ von \pageref{LastPage}} % Set the footer to show the current page and total number of pages
\rofoot{\today}

\begin{document}
    \title{Konferenzprotokoll}
    \subtitle{\mytitle}
    \author{Dr. Norman Patrick Benner}
    %\maketitle
    
    \begin{minipage}[l]{0.5\textwidth}
        \Large Konferenzprotokoll\\
        \large{\mytitle}\\
        \begin{tabularx}{.9\linewidth}{|p{4cm}X|}
            \hline
            Datum:&\\
            Klassenkonferenz:&\\
            %Fachkonferenz:&\Zl
            %Fachbereichskonferenz&\Zl\\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[l]{.45\textwidth}
        \small
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Anwesende Teilnehmer} \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{} \\
            \hline
            Entschuldigt & Nicht entschuldigt \\
            \hline
            &\\\hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}
    \lipsum
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Leider hat weder '''  Code''', noch CTRL K noch 8 LEerzeichen korrekt für den Code funktioniert, warum?

Comment: Hi this is an English language site, could you translate your question, thank you

Comment: never do `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  \usepackage{fontspec}` the first specifies 8bit fonts for pdftex, the second is only usable  with luatex or xetex and sets up Unicode fonts, use one or the other, depending which tex system you are using.

Comment: Your code contains commands such as `\Ab` and `\Zl` that are not defined in the MWE, It is hard to tell how the result should look like without knowing what these commands are supposed to do. Also, note that font-size changing commands such as `\Large` or `\large` don't take an argument, but they function like switches. So you should use `{\large text}` instead of `\large{text}`.

Comment: You have not said what output or error you get, and are using a non standard font,  i don't have FuturaBookBT  so I just get `! Package fontspec Error: The font "FuturaBookBT" cannot be found.` and no usable output, can  you demonstrate your problem using standard fonts?

Comment: There is no error. The font is now commented, does not change anything.  With exactly this code, the footline ist too small for the image and the image begins exactly with the page.
By using the gemoetry pack  i can change this, but it is not clear to me why the footheigt at the beginning does not work. I am told "footheight is too small", it is recommenden to change footheight manually from the editor, allthough the editor tells me, that lualatex did change the footheight. But setting the footheight in [] after document does not change anything.
What is wrong, i can't find.
Thanks, Patrick

Comment: You should always try to minimize your example. There is a lot of code, that is not related to your problem. This could even makes it hard to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KOMA-Script has a build in feature to visualize the page header and footer: package `scrlayer-scrpage` with option `draft`. But IMHO the output with measuring in the background and the foreground is somehow confusing. So here an example with only one measure per head an foot:

```
\documentclass[%
%  headheight=60pt,
%  headinclude=false,% default
%  headinclude=true,
%  footheight=60pt,
%  footinclude=false,% default
%  footinclude=true,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  head,
  contents=\layercontentsmeasure
]{showhead}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  foot,
  contents=\layercontentsmeasure
]{showfoot}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{show}{showhead,showfoot}

\newcommand*{\emptypage}{\mbox{}\thispagestyle{show}\newpage}

\begin{document}

\emptypage

\end{document}
```

Now, you can remove the `%` before some of the options to see, how the influence the size and position of page header and page footer.

For example here an example that shows the change, from the example above to an example with `headheight=60pt,headinclude=true,footheight=60pt,footinclude=true`:

[image]

You can do similar for real page styles using `scrlayer-scrpage`. Here an example, that also illustrates, how the vertical alignment inside the header and footer works and what happens, if the (header or) footer does not fit:

```latex
\documentclass[%
  headheight=60pt,
  headtopline=true,
  headsepline=true,
%   headinclude=false,
%   headinclude=true,
%  footheight=60pt,
   footsepline=true,
   footbotline=true
%  footinclude=false,
%  footinclude=true,  
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[autoenlargeheadfoot=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  head,
  contents={\color{gray}\layercontentsmeasure}
]{showhead}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  foot,
  contents={\color{gray}\layercontentsmeasure}
]{showfoot}
%\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{showhead,showfoot}% acivate this to
                                                       % visualize the header
                                                       % and footer

\chead{\color{red}Example Header}
\cfoot{\color{red}Example\\Footer}

\newcommand*{\emptypage}{\mbox{}\newpage}

\begin{document}

\emptypage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Additionally there is a warning in the `log`:

```
Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \footheight to low.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                At least 27.2pt needed,
(scrlayer-scrpage)                but only 17.0pt found.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                You should enlarge \footheight,
(scrlayer-scrpage)                e.g., setting typearea's option
(scrlayer-scrpage)                `footheight=27.2pt' on input line 37.
```

Note: I've added option `autoenlargeheadfoot=false` here to avoid, that `scrlayer-scrpage` automatically increases the height of the page footer, because this could warp the output of the separation lines and the measure lines. Feel free to test, what happens without this option not only for one page, but also if you add a second `\emptypage`.

But maybe your question is somehow different: **How to add an image to the page header without increasing the reserved height of the page header?**

Use, e.g., `\smash`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead{\smash{\includegraphics[height=50pt]{example-image}}}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Note: It is you responsibility to ensure that the image fits.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me a lot. 
Some further questions:
Is thera a way to change the distance between head an page? (areaset, geometry, bestway?
In my code, the headheight did not change. Now it does. I do not know what i changed (didn't change anything). What option can be wrong?

Comment: @Patrick What do you mean with "distance between head an page"? The distance between the top edge of the page and the top edge of the head? [This would be another question.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/) The calculation used by `typearea` is documented in chapter 2 of the user manuals. It changes, e.g., if you change `DIV`. And it changes, if you use `\areaset`. But there isn't an option to change it directly. But there is a note about using `geometry`, and an option `usegeometry` to improve the combination if you want to change only some parameters but not all manually.